# Query not being read for a isset function for drop down menu

Tags: php, html

I have this form:

```
 <form method='post' name='form_filter' >
                                Filter By:
                                <select name ="select_name">
                                    <option>...</option>
                                    <option value = "plowest">Price Lowest</option>
                                    <option value = "phighest">Price Highest</option>
                                    <option value ="endingsoon">Ending Soon</option>
                                    <option value = "newlylisted">Newly Listed</option>
                                </select>
                                <input type='submit' value = 'Filter'>
                        </form>
```

And then in php I am doing this. For example if user selects Price Lowest, I run a certain query. If he selects Price Highest, I select another query and so on.
My PHP code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['value'])) {
                        echo "HELLO";
                        if($_POST['value'] == 'plowest'){
                            echo($_POST['value']);
                             $query = "select *from(Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NAME ASC) as rn, $computerUserName.items.* FROM $computerUserName.items) where rn between $offset and $variable";
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                    $query = "select * from(Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rn, $computerUserName.items.* FROM $computerUserName.items) where rn between $offset and $variable";
                    }                        
                    $stmt = db2_prepare($connection, $query);
                    $result = db2_execute($stmt);
```

But for some reason, if I select the Price Lowest(with value plowest), it still queries the else.

Comment: Have you tried to check the content of `$_POST['value']` with something like [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.var-dump.php)?

Comment: I placed it in the else and it returned null. Because no option was selected from drop down. I placed it in the if, doesn't return anything. Even after I selected the price lowest option. Seems like for some reason my if statement is never being read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['select_name'])) {
    echo($_POST['select_name']);
    if($_POST['select_name'] == 'plowest'){
        $query = "select *from(Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NAME ASC) as rn, $computerUserName.items.* FROM $computerUserName.items) where rn between $offset and $variable";
    }
    else{
        $query = "select * from(Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rn, $computerUserName.items.* FROM $computerUserName.items) where rn between $offset and $variable";
    }                        
    $stmt = db2_prepare($connection, $query);
    $result = db2_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: But I want to display * if no option is chosen from the dropdown.

Comment: And order by name if plowest is chosen

Comment: Oh I see what you are talking about. It should be $_POST['select_name'] rathen than $_POST['value]. It works now